# Stop reusing cell to get fresh data in Ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created a `viewController` that has a `UITableView`. I have made a custom cell with the `UILabel` and the `UIImageView`. For some reasons I am using my on custom cell view inside it.

Now that I have a array/list of models, in which I have a field of IsSlectedForList, I am using this field. If it is true I have to mark my check box and if it is false then I will leave it as it is.

**My Probelm:** 
My problem is that everything is working fine but when I scroll the list I have observed that other cell's checkbox is also got selected until and unless I go to bottom of list.

**What I have done:** I believe Like android We have to stop reusing previous cell so to get new fresh cell with right data. But cant figure out how it should be done in IOS since I am new to ios.

> Please help me in it. I just want that those rows which are not
>   selected should not get checked on scroll.

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = lvOptionalClasses.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellSSClasses") as! ItemSSClassLevelsTableViewCell


    if let list = listClassLevles {

        let classLevel = list[indexPath.row]
        cell.awakeFromNib()


        cell.tvClassLevelName.text = classLevel.Name
        cell.setSelected(false, animated: true)

        if let isSelected = classLevel.IsSelectedInList{
            if(isSelected){
            cell.setSelected(isSelected, animated: true)
                print(classLevel.Name)
            }
        }
    }


    return cell
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.setSelected(false, animated: false)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

listClassLevles![indexPath.row].IsSelectedInList = true


}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      listClassLevles![indexPath.row].IsSelectedInList = false
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.init(rawValue: 3)!
}
```

Comment: The issue you are facing is not related to reuse of cells. You should put else block also with if condition. like if(isSelected){ // code }else{ // code}.

Comment: I have done this too. take a look,  at this line cell.setSelected(false, animated: true)

Comment: But if isSelected is false, the block will not get executed and may result in inconsistent UI on cell.

Comment: well I have done as you said, but not working

Answer (score 0):

In your code insert condition in else block also

```
if let isSelected = classLevel.IsSelectedInList{
   if(isSelected){
        cell.setSelected(isSelected, animated: true)
        print(classLevel.Name)
    } else {
        //You must write your else logic here too
    }
} else {
        //You must write your else logic here too
}
```

Comment: Does controller commes everytime this block? if let list = listClassLevles {

Comment: yeah, I have breakpoint and I can see block is running correctly